# Trigger a compile error when a variable name is used

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

I am using a tool called Rational Rose for C++. When a variable name which includes the word "interface" is defined, the tool stops working and prints out a blank error message.

The support issue can be seen here:
https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21271841&wv=1

I would like to add a preprocessor directive such that when the variable name "interface" is used, a compile error will be displayed.

Something along the lines of:

```
#define interface #error The Keyword interface is not permitted
```

Comment: You want to use the pre-processor to fix a bug with a third-party tool? Why do I get the feeling that this is clearly the wrong approach?

Comment: I wish we could use another tool, as well, but it is currently company policy to use the IBM tool set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use preprocessor statements inside preprocessor statements.

However, you can force a compiler error along these lines:

```
#define interface -ERROR_interface_is_a_reserved_symbol
```

On windows (MS compiler) this would point you to the code line with the error:

```
yourfile.cpp(82): error C2065: 'ERROR_interface_is_a_reserved_symbol' : undeclared identifier
```

Would agree with others here though that it seems to be the wrong place for a solution to your problem.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by DeadMG, this solution would only work if you're looking for exact variable names, rather than partial matches.

Comment: This solution does not quite work. I tried adding the define but since the define can be a valid variable name, it replaces all the words interface with ERROR_interface_is_a_reserved_symbol and everything compiles successfully.

Comment: I modified it so that the define is included twice and it works: #define interface ERROR_interface_is_a_reserved_symbol ERROR_interface_is_a_reserved_symbol

Comment: Ah, sorry, gave you the variant for type names and keywords. I updated the answer. Your solution works, but it's enough (for MS compiler) to add a '-' before the symbol. It screws up the type specification so that the variable name is reported undeclared.

Comment: Adding the "-" in front does not quite work, either. Although the code fails to compile, the error message given does not print the ERROR_interface_is_a_reserved_symbol message, at least when using GCC.

Comment: That may be. Guess the trick is to find the working way for your particular compiler. This is for MS.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the preprocessor to gain partial matches. If I write `IInterface` and `EInterface` and `ILikeBigInterfacesAndICannotLie`, then you cannot use the preprocessor to match them all.

Comment: I don't need to match on them all. Just the exact word "interface".